# Block Mysql query until is updated

Tags: php, mysql

I am curious, is there a way to make the query block (wait) until new rows are inserted?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Maybe [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) will help? You can hold the changes until you are ready to **commit** them. I guess it's sort of like a block...

Comment: Whats the point? Why not just run the query after the rows are inserted? It would help to know what the reason behind this is :)

Comment: It was my understanding that inserts will lock read operations until they complete.

Comment: No, there is no way to have a MySQL SELECT query block until an INSERT occurs on the table(s) queried. @landons, INSERTS generally do block, but only during the actual execution of the INSERT; for obvious reasons, INSERTs which haven't been run yet don't block anything.

Comment: You know it's a poorly phrased question when comments are trying to answer each other.  What's the concern--data integrity?  Waiting for a different script to finish executing before proceeding?  If you execute an insert, then a select, they will execute in order, and your data will be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases I can see causing you to raise this question:

1. Large batch `INSERT` statements, ie:

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES
     (1, 'Tom', '2013-01-31'),
     (2, 'Dick', '2013-02-28'),
     (3, 'Harry', '2013-03-31'),
     ...
   ```

   In this case MySQL does the locking *internally*, so you do not have to do anything. Any query that requires the use of 'mytable' will be deferred until the insert is completed.
2. Repetitive single `INSERT` statements, ie:

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES (1, 'Tom', '2013-01-31');
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES (2, 'Dick', '2013-02-28');
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES (3, 'Harry', '2013-03-31');
   ...
   ```

   In *this* case the table unlocks between statements and the only way to properly "lock" the table is to use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). [Note: myISAM does not support transactions, you must be using InnoDB or BDB tables. ie:

   ```
   START TRANSACTION;
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES (1, 'Tom', '2013-01-31');
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES (2, 'Dick', '2013-02-28');
   INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, date) VALUES (3, 'Harry', '2013-03-31');
   ...
   COMMIT;
   ```